# How to get the configuration file path within JAR file for KafkaProducer SSL setup?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a JAR file with below structure:

```
example.jar
 |
 +-org
 |  +-springframework
 |     +-boot
 |        +-loader.jar
 +-BOOT-INF
    +-classes
    |  +- kafka
    |     truststore.jks ==> I want to get the path here
    +-lib
       +-dependency1.jar
```

How can I get the configuration file path, only path (string) of 'kafka/truststore.jks' file ?

Because I am applying the SSL for KafkaProducer, I using below code and it work fine on local:

```
@Value("classpath:kafka/truststore.jks")
private org.springframework.core.io.Resource sslTruststoreResource;

...

String sslTruststoreLocation = sslTruststoreResource.getFile().getAbsolutePath(); // ==\> ***it throw FileNotFoundException here on deployed Server, local env run fine !***

Map\<String, Object\> config = Maps.newHashMap();
config.put("ssl.truststore.location", sslTruststoreLocation);
```

but when I deploy on Server, it throw FileNotFoundException :(

After many days to research, I found that the **sslTruststoreResource.getFile()** will be fail for JAR file case as mentioned at [here](https://smarterco.de/java-load-file-from-classpath-in-spring-boot/)
The **sslTruststoreResource.getInputStream()** or **sslTruststoreResource.getFilename()** are ok for JAR file but they are not path I need for kafka configuration.

In my project, the 'truststore.jks' file is located as below:

```
src
-- java
-- resources
. -- kafka
    -- truststore.jks
```

So, is there any solution for my issue ? Thank you.

I tried to use ClassPathResource, ResourcePatternResolver but they not working

Comment: ClassPathResource should work (but you need to extract the file out of the JAR), so what did you try with that? Also, running a JAR locally and remotely should show the same behavior... But could you not deploy an external JKS file next to the JAR instead of inside, then use a real file path? Or, get the InputStream / content, then create a file on disk, then use that path in config

Comment: @OneCricketeer yes the ClassPathResource is not working for "config.put("ssl.truststore.location", sslTruststoreLocation);"

Is there any way to point to the JKS file in jar for kafka configuration instead of copy that file to outsite of jar ?

Comment: Not that I am aware of

Answer (score 0):

After many ways I still could not get the path from JKS file then I copy it to another path out of jar file where my code can refer to its path

```
final String FILE_NAME = env.getProperty("kafka.metadata.ssl.truststore.location");
    String sslTruststoreLocation = "*-imf-kafka-client.truststore.jks";
    try {
        InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(FILE_NAME);

        // Get the destination path where contains JKS file
        final String HOME_DIR = System.getProperty("user.home");
        final Path destPath = Paths.get(HOME_DIR, "tmp");
        if (!Files.isDirectory(destPath)) {
            Files.createDirectories(destPath);
        }

        // Copy JKS file to destination path
        sslTruststoreLocation = destPath.toFile().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + FILE_NAME;
        File uploadedFile = new File(sslTruststoreLocation);
        if(!uploadedFile.exists()) {
            uploadedFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            uploadedFile.createNewFile();
            FileCopyUtils.copy(is, new FileOutputStream(sslTruststoreLocation));
            log.debug("Copied {} file from resources dir to {} done !", FILE_NAME, sslTruststoreLocation);
        }

        config.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG, sslTruststoreLocation);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        final String message = "The " + sslTruststoreLocation + " file not found to construct a KafkaProducer";
        log.error(message);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a [known issue in Kafka](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7685).

Spring Boot propose a [workaround](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/710#issuecomment-398193974) similar to yours.